# Extract date from a column of type date in SQL/ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I've a column of type `DATE`. How can I compare it with hours field of `SYSDATE` to perform some operation?

Column name: `DateColumn` - of type `DATE`

**Requirement:**
A search condition from the table considering the hours from `DateColumn` and should check if it is less than 10 hours from hours in `SYSDATE`

for ex, if hours in `DateColumn` is `15` and the current hours from `SYSDATE` is `20`, as the hours difference is less than 10 hours, it should satisfy the condition.

I need something like this:

```
 SELECT EMP_ID FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE SYSDATE(something to extract hours) - 
 DATECOLUMN(something to consider hours) < 10;
```

**EDIT :**
It should consider the difference between the days too.

Like if `DateColumn` has `20-09-2017 15:00:000` and `SYSDATE` is `21-09-2017 20:00:000`, it should fail as the hours difference is `29`

Comment: @ShannonSeverance I am old skool Oracle Consultant :P

Comment: If `DateColumn` is `20` and `SYSDATE` is `4` is that within 10 hours? `20+10 = 30 = 6 MOD 24` and `4 < 6`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to consider that `20:00` is only 8 hours before `04:00` then you can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM   employees
WHERE  ABS( MOD( ( SYSDATE - DateColumn ) * 24, 24 ) ) < 10;
```

If you need to include dates as well then:

```
SELECT *
FROM   EMPLOYEES
WHERE  DateColumn BETWEEN SYSDATE - INTERVAL '10' HOUR
                      AND SYSDATE + INTERVAL '10' HOUR;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT EMP_ID FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'HH24')) - TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'HH24')) < 10;
```

Comment: This only compares the hours field. I should have asked clearly. My bad.  It should also consider the dates. Like if DateColumn has 20-09-2017 15:00:000 and SYSDATE is 21-09-2017 20:00:000, it should fail as the hours difference is 29.

Comment: In oracle when you substract 2 date datatypes you get the difference in hours. Can you work it out or you need more help @intruder ?

Comment: It's showing the difference in days when I use this:
WHERE SYSDATE-DATECOLUMN < 10  --> this shows from past 10 days. How should I parse it to consider the hours?

Comment: A day has 24 hours x 60 minutes x 60 seconds, the answer is already provided by @MT0

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`extract`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm):

```
SELECT emp_id 
FROM   employee
WHERE  EXTRACT(HOUR FROM SYSDATE) - EXTRACT(HOUR FROM datecolumn) < 10;
```